# How to route two projects in htdocs with apache and ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache, react-router

I have two projects and want to put in two separate folders htdocs/meteo and htdocs/todo

I've not installed react-router at now, but can I take some example of how to do that?

My first project code is only in the App.js file.

How can I route in htdocs/meteo this project?

The code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";

import Chart from "./chart";
import "./App.css";

const customMarker = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: require("../src/images/marker.png"),
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [10, 41],
  popupAnchor: [2, -40]
});

class Map extends React.Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date()
  };

  onChange = date =>
    this.setState({
      date
    });

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      coords: [
        {
          lat: 41.19197,
          lng: 25.33719
        },
        {
          lat: 41.26352,
          lng: 25.1471
        },
        {
          lat: 41.26365,
          lng: 25.24215
        },
        {
          lat: 41.26369,
          lng: 25.33719
        },
        {
          lat: 41.26365,
          lng: 25.43224
        },
        {
          lat: 41.26352,
          lng: 25.52728
        },
        {
          lat: 41.2633,
          lng: 25.62233
        },
        {
          lat: 41.263,
          lng: 25.71737
        }
      ],
      zoom: 8,
      minZoom: 7,
      maxZoom: 10,
      dats: null,
      loading: true,
      dataAPI: null,
      id: 4,
      temp: null,
      lng: 0,
      lat: 0
    };
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // this.getData();
  }

  async loadData(data) {
    this.setState({
      id: data.id
    });

    this.getData();
  }

  async getData() {
    var id = this.state.id;
    const url = `http://194.141.118.43:3000/?date=2019-10-20&id=${id}&daysForward=8`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      dataAPI: data.aladinModel[0],
      loading: false
    });
    this.setState({
      temp: data.aladinModel[0],
      loading: false
    });
    this.setState({
      dats: data.aladinModel[0],
      loading: false
    });
  }

  async onChangeHandler(e) {
    debugger;
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    const { coords, zoom } = this.state;
    return (
      <LeafletMap
        center={[42.733883, 25.48583]}
        zoom={zoom}
        minZoom={this.state.minZoom}
        maxZoom={this.state.maxZoom}
        style={{
          height: "100vh",
          width: "100vw"
        }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://plovdiv.meteo.bg" target="_blank">НИМХ - Пловдив</a> '
          url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />

        {coords.map(({ lat, lng }, index) => (
          <Marker
            position={[lat, lng]}
            icon={customMarker}
            key={index}
            onClick={() =>
              this.loadData({
                id: index,
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
              })
            }
          >
            <div className="leaflet-popup-content">
              <Chart
                dats={this.state.dats}
                index={this.state.id}
                lng={lng}
                lat={lat}
              />{" "}
            </div>{" "}
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </LeafletMap>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

In my package.json I set `"homepage": "http://192.168.1.10/meteo/"`

How can I route the App page to this URL address?

Comment: is this react project right? for working in local there is no need to set "hompage" in package.json.

Comment: Do you want to redirect from one project to another?

Comment: I want to put second react project in htdocs/todo ?

Comment: okay, you can put bro. what's your problem in tat?